# Rake - capture :task_name as an option?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I am watching a Peepcode screencast [Play by Play: Jim Weirich](https://peepcode.com/products/play-by-play-jimweirich-ruby).

He executes a rake task that appears to pass the final task name as an option.

[image: rake -g projec:ruby:demo]

See how the task :demo creates a "demo" folder. How was this done?

**EDIT:**

Thanks, Alex.Bullard.

So with something like this:

```
namespace :project do
    namespace :ruby do
        rule "" do |t|
            puts t.name
        end
    end
end
```

Running `$ rake project:ruby:demo` outputs `project:ruby:demo`.

Do I have to `t.name.split(":")` or is there a way to grab just that final name?

Comment: There's not enough context to understand what's going on. What was the current directory when `rake` was run? From that snippet, it's not clear that any directory is being created.

Comment: Good point. In fact, watching this part again, I think he may have a :demo task defined and just happen to be in a demo folder. In any case, I learned a new trick from @Alex.Bullard below, so that's cool. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a task like this:

```
  namespace :test do
    rule "" do |t|
      # t.name is 'test::[whatever]"
    end
  end
```

Then the `""` task will act as a catchall and you can use its name as an argument for whatever you want

Comment: Yes! Thanks. Now do I have to `t.name.split(":")`, or is there a built-in way to grab just that last name? (I've updated my question above with more details).